# Java - JUnit testing for balanced BinarySearchTree

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, binary-search-tree

I've written a working Binary Search Tree and want to construct some JUnit tests to go along with it. I'm working on three: one to find the maximum value (InOrder traversal), one to remove this maximum value, and one to check if my Binary Tree is balanced. I've written the first two, but can't quite figure out how to nail the last test -- checking for balance. I'd appreciate some guidance, as I feel like I've overlooked something.

My test methods:

```
public class BSTreePreLabTest {
@Test
public void testFindMax() {
    BSTree<Integer> tree = new BSTree<Integer>();
    tree.addElement(15);
    tree.addElement(16);
    tree.addElement(17);
    tree.addElement(18);
    tree.addElement(19);
    tree.addElement(20);    
    assertEquals("20", tree.findMax().toString());
}


@Test
public void testRemoveMax() {
    BSTree<Integer> tree = new BSTree<Integer>();
    tree.addElement(15);
    tree.addElement(16);
    tree.addElement(17);
    tree.addElement(18);
    tree.addElement(19);
    tree.addElement(20);    
    tree.removeMax();
    assertEquals("Inorder traversal: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]", tree.toString());
}
```

And my main BinarySearchTree method, for reference, if needed:

```
public class BSTree<T> {

private BSTreeNode<T> root = null;
private int count;

public BSTree(T element) {
    root = new BSTreeNode<T>(element);
    count = 1;
}

public BSTree() {
    root = null;
    count = 0;
}

public void addElement(T element) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        root = new BSTreeNode<T>(element);
    } 
    else {
        BSTreeNode<T> current = root;
        BSTreeNode<T> previous = null;
        Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>) element;
        while (current != null) {
            if (comparableElement.compareTo(current.getElement()) < 0) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getLeft();
            } 
            else {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getRight();
            }
        }
        BSTreeNode<T> newNode = new BSTreeNode<T>(element);
        if (comparableElement.compareTo(previous.getElement()) < 0) 
            previous.setLeft(newNode);          
        else
            previous.setRight(newNode);
    }
    count++;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

public int size() {
    return count;
}

public T find(T targetElement) throws ElementNotFoundException {
    BSTreeNode<T> current = findNode(targetElement, root);

    if (current == null)
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("BSTree");

    return (current.getElement());
}

private BSTreeNode<T> findNode(T targetElement, BSTreeNode<T> next) {
    if (next == null)
        return null;

    if (next.getElement().equals(targetElement))
        return next;

    BSTreeNode<T> temp = findNode(targetElement, next.getLeft());

    if (temp == null)
        temp = findNode(targetElement, next.getRight());

    return temp;
}

public T removeElement(T targetElement) throws ElementNotFoundException {
    T result = null;

    if (isEmpty())
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("BSTree");
    else {
        BSTreeNode<T> parent = null;
        if (((Comparable<T>) targetElement).equals(root.getElement())) {
            result = root.getElement();
            BSTreeNode<T> temp = replacement(root);
            if (temp == null)
                root = null;
            else {
                root.setElement(temp.getElement());
                root.setRight(temp.getRight());
                root.setLeft(temp.getLeft());
            }
        } else {
            parent = root;
            if (((Comparable) targetElement).compareTo(root.getElement()) < 0)
                result = removeElement(targetElement, root.getLeft(), parent);
            else
                result = removeElement(targetElement, root.getRight(), parent);
        }
    }
    count--;
    return result;
}

private T removeElement(T targetElement, BSTreeNode<T> node,
        BSTreeNode<T> parent) throws ElementNotFoundException {
    T result = null;

    if (node == null)
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("BSTree");
    else {
        if (((Comparable<T>) targetElement).equals(node.getElement())) {
            result = node.getElement();
            BSTreeNode<T> temp = replacement(node);
            if (parent.getRight() == node)
                parent.setRight(temp);
            else
                parent.setLeft(temp);
        } else {
            parent = node;
            if (((Comparable) targetElement).compareTo(node.getElement()) < 0)
                result = removeElement(targetElement, node.getLeft(),
                        parent);
            else
                result = removeElement(targetElement, node.getRight(),
                        parent);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private BSTreeNode<T> replacement(BSTreeNode<T> node) {
    BSTreeNode<T> result = null;

    if ((node.getLeft() == null) && (node.getRight() == null))
        result = null;

    else if ((node.getLeft() != null) && (node.getRight() == null))
        result = node.getLeft();

    else if ((node.getLeft() == null) && (node.getRight() != null))
        result = node.getRight();

    else {
        BSTreeNode<T> current = node.getRight();
        BSTreeNode<T> parent = node;

        while (current.getLeft() != null) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.getLeft();
        }

        current.setLeft(node.getLeft());
        if (node.getRight() != current) {
            parent.setLeft(current.getRight());
            current.setRight(node.getRight());
        }

        result = current;
    }

    return result;
}

public String toString() 
{
    ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>();
    inOrder(root, temp);
    return "Inorder traversal: " + temp.toString();
}

public Iterator<T> iterator()
{
    return iteratorInOrder();
}

public Iterator<T> iteratorInOrder()
{
    ArrayList<T> tempList = new ArrayList<T>();
    inOrder(root, tempList);

    return tempList.iterator();
}

public T findMax(){
    T result = null;
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new ElementNotFoundException ("binary tree");
    else {
        BSTreeNode<T> current = root;

        while (current.getRight() != null)
            current = current.getRight();

        result = current.getElement();
    }

return result;
}

public T removeMax(){
    T result = null;

    if (isEmpty())
         throw new ElementNotFoundException("binary tree");
    else 
    {
       if (root.getRight() == null) 
       {
          result =  root.getElement();
          root = root.getLeft();
       }
       else 
       {
            BSTreeNode<T> parent = root;
            BSTreeNode<T> current = root.getRight();

            while (current.getRight() != null) 
            {
               parent = current;
               current = current.getRight();
            }

            result =  current.getElement();
            parent.setRight(current.getLeft());
         }

       count--;
    }

    return result;
}

protected void inOrder(BSTreeNode<T> node, ArrayList<T> tempList) {
    if (node != null) {
        inOrder(node.getLeft(), tempList);
        tempList.add(node.getElement());
        inOrder(node.getRight(), tempList);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to find the height of left and right sub-tree

```
int height(Node node) 
{
    if (node == null)
        return 0;

    return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
}
```

then, you can write another method to check if the tree is balanced

```
boolean isBalanced(Node node) 
{
    int lh;
    int rh;

    if (node == null)
        return true;

    lh = height(node.left);
    rh = height(node.right);

    if (Math.abs(lh - rh) <= 1
            && isBalanced(node.left)
            && isBalanced(node.right)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then, you can write a JUnit test case to test your isBalanced().

I hope this helps!